# nginx responds with 404 Not Found (Single Page App)

Tags: nginx, server, single-page-application

I have a Single Page Application with regular Browser Router (without hash). Whenever someone navigates through page and hits refresh button nginx tries to find file on this path. So if someone is on `mypage.com/about` nginx looks for `about` file and responds with 404 Not Found. How to fix this issue?

I'm thinking about specifying a location with wildcard - `mypage.com/*` except `/api` tho, because every backend endpoint in this app starts with `api`.  How to match all paths except one? This is how my config looks like:

```
upstream frontend {
    server frontend:3000;
}

upstream backend {
    server backend:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_set_header Host            \$http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For \$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://frontend;
        proxy_redirect default;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why do your proxy requests for frontend app ? I assume that you are using some kind of development server to serve your frontend application. It is better to build your frontend application to static files and serve them as regular static files, without any server except the nginx.

As for your question, if you will build your frontend application into static files you may configure location in nginx like this:

```
root /var/www/your_site;
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

where index.html is entrypoint into your application and the root path should be configured to place where it stored.

If you still want to serve frontend application from development server through nginx you may configure nginx to handle errors from upstream and point error page to root of dev server.

In this case following directives should help you:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_intercept_errors
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page

Comment: I'm actually using nginx to serve those static files. Is it a bad practice to proxy requests for the frontend?

Comment: It is enough to serve static files only with nginx. No need to involve any other servers.

Comment: Oh I did this because I'm using docker containers, and it's much easier just to expose some port on the containers :) Otherwise I would need to copy whole frontend build into nginx container

Comment: @feerlay you may use `volumes`. In this case you even don't need to restart any container (or server in it) to update your frontend application - just to update files in mounted directory.

Comment: Oh, that's actually interesting :) Gonna check it!

Comment: thank you so much! I solved this problem using volumes!