# Nginx and containers : refreshing my SPA gives 404 error

Tags: docker, nginx, vuejs2, reverse-proxy

My problem is that when I'm refreshing the page, I always get "404 page not found".

Things to put in mind is that I'm exposing my SPA Vuejs frontend as a docker container, and this container has Nginx installed.
and im using this command to expose 4002 port to my host

```
docker run -v vol_Front:/usr/share/nginx/html --name front --rm -d -p 4002:80 myfront
```

and my nginx configuratio is as follows :

```
server{
        listen 80;
        server_name MY_SERVER_IP;
        location /front1/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4002/;
        }
        location /front2/ {
          # another frontend 
        }
}
```

if I'm accessing: **http://MY_SERVER_IP/front1** It works very well, and if I'm navigating to Dashboard for example  **http://MY_SERVER_IP/front1/Dashboard**  it works too, but when I'm refreshing in the same page (Dashboards page) I get a 404 error.

solutions I tried :
PS : i didn't quite understand most of this solutions but here are some of them:

- [try_files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48834455/nginx-responds-with-404-not-found-single-page-app)

  ```
  location /front1/ {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:4002/;
       try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
       }
  ```

this only redirects me to the Nginx default welcome page

- @frontend Location

```
      location /front1/ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @frontend;
      }
    
      location @frontend {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:4002;
      }
```

this gives an internal server Error 500.

- point to the exposed volume from docker with Nginx instead of using
  proxy_pass.

I didn't try this because the reason for even using docker container is to avoid this (there is no particular reason for that just experimenting with new things )

**PS:**  I'm all new to Docker and Nginx or DevOps (i guess) in  general any help would be very appreciated
thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to use proxy pass? Since your frontend application is built, you can serve static files with NGINX directly. That way, your directive `try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;` would be sufficient.

Comment: @NemanjaRanković because he is using his front-end app as a container. By the way, same issue here. Any solution ?